# How can I graphically update a Grafana table with Spring Boot Rest API?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, grafana

In my Spring Boot project I have created a Rest Controller that performs a GET type REST API that executes a query on a postgres table linked to grafana ... I want this table to update automatically every 5 minutes without me having to run the called from my Swagger.

RestController:

```
    @GetMapping("/Missing-Device/alls")
    public List<MissingDeviceEntity> getAllMissingDeviceEntity() throws Exception{

final String METHOD_NAME = "getAllMissingDeviceEntity()";
        try {
            startLog(METHOD_NAME);
            final List<MissingDeviceEntity> result = monterotondoMarittimoService.getAllMissingDeviceEntity();
            endLog(METHOD_NAME, result);
            return result;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            errorLog(METHOD_NAME, e);
            throw e;
        }
}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
    public List<MissingDeviceEntity> getAllMissingDeviceEntity() throws Exception {
        final String methodName = "getAllMissingDeviceEntity()";
        try {
            this.startLog(methodName);

            List<MMEntity> MMEs = mMDao.getAllMissingDeviceEntity();
            List<MissingDeviceEntity> MDEs = new ArrayList<>();

            if (!MMEs.isEmpty()) {
                missingDeviceDao.deleteAll();

                for (MMEntity MME : MMEs) {
                    MissingDeviceEntity MDE = new MissingDeviceEntity();
                    MDE.setColumns(MME.getColumns());
                    MDE.setTime(MME.getTime());
                    MDEs.add(MDE);
                }
                missingDeviceDao.saveAll(MDEs);
            }

            this.endLog(methodName, MDEs);
            return MDEs;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            this.errorLog(methodName, e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

How can I do??

Answer (score 0):

Use [@Scheduler](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) tag in Spring to run the call periodically. [Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks#schedule-a-task-at-a-fixed-rate)